# Dynamic Gantt Chart in Excel

Tags: excel, charts, excel-formula, gantt-chart

I am following this link to create my Gantt Chart in excel. https://www.officetimeline.com/gantt-chart-excel

Everything works fine, but I am trying to create this chart dynamically by using a pivot table. Let me explain. The pivot table has the values that are needed for the charge, but it does also have 1 value that will be use as a filter, doing this, I should be able to create a gantt chart for A or B, or A and B.

The challenging that I am facing is that if A has 200 task, and B only 10, the chart is taking all the "200" lines instead of only the ones that contains data. I looked everywhere and couldnt find a way to "skip" empty cells. Any idea?

Comment: What empty cells? Why would there be empty cells in the data source?

Answer (score 0):

In this screenshot the problem you describe does not come up.

The Pivot chart has the tasks in the rows area and sums start date and duration in the values area.  A slicer (or a filter) can be used to show all projects or just one project.

[image]

Comment: The problem is that the data is coming up from a pivot table. I am not using a pivot chart. So when the pivot table changes, the number of rows changed too ( A & B example) causing the chart to go crazy.